# Правильное использование ООП PHP

Tags: php

У меня вопрос архитектурного характера. Обычно я создаю методы, которые далее вызывают следующее методы. В итоге получается создав класс получаю законченную работу приложения. Есть ли в этом архитектурный косяк или же это в порядке вещей?

Comment: Мне кажется что косяков тут нет. Иначе как - все методы в одном классе? Тогда о каком ООП может идти речь.

Comment: У вас всё приложение в одном классе?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно понять что такое класс, саму его суть....вот скажем есть человек, собака,врач и яблоко - это 4 разных объекта и соответсвенно 4 разных класса..
Нельзя чтобы у нас был класс СобакаЧеловекоВрачеЯблоко т.к это бессмыслица.

Соответвенно у каждого класса есть методы например человек и собака могут бежать это их методы, у всех объектов есть свойства - например у всех этих 4 объектов есть высота это их свойство, у каждого объекта свои свойства.

Также классы могут наследовать другие классы например - врач по сути тоже является человеком, т.е все что умеет делать человек умеет делать и врач...т.е врач наследует класс человека, но обратное не верно..не каждый человек умеет то что умеет врач - это базовые принцнипы которые вам нужно усвоить.

Так же и у вас в одном классе мало вероятно что может находится вся логика т.к скорее всего вы создали СобакаЧеловекоВрачеЯблоко - которое умеет и ходить, и лечить и лаять.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, каждый класс создается максимально независимым и законченным элементом, который отвечает только за свою конкретную часть.

Если у вас все именно так, тогда все прекрасно!

Например, есть класс двигатель, у которого есть свои методы работы и свойства. Класс машина будет использовать класс двигатель. Класс двигатель не зависит от машины. Машина так же не зависит от конкретного класса двигателя. При этом вам ничто не мешает создать свой отличный от базового класс двигателя и использовать его для своего объекта-машины.